# Triangulating a Plane in WebGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, gl-triangle-strip

I'm trying to construct a plane out of triangles in WebGL. My code for the constructor looks like this:

```
function plane( points_transform )
{

    shape.call(this); // Inherit class shape’s array members by calling parent constructor
    if( !arguments.length) return; // Pass no arguments if you just want to make an empty dummy object that inherits everything, for populating other shapes
    this.populate( this, points_transform ); // Otherwise, a new triangle immediately populates its own arrays with triangle points,
    this.init_buffers(); // Then sends its arrays to the graphics card into new buffers
}

inherit(plane, shape); 
plane.prototype.populate = function( recipient, points_transform) 
{
    var offset = recipient.vertices.length;        
    var index_offset = recipient.indices.length;                // Recipient's previous size

    recipient.vertices.push( vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,1,0), vec3(0,1,0), vec3(1,0,0), vec3(2,1,0), vec3(2,0,0) );
    recipient.normals.push( vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,1) );
    // recipient.texture_coords.push( vec2(0,0), vec2(0,1), vec2(1,0), vec2(1,1), vec2(2,0), vec2(2,1) );
    recipient.indices.push( offset + 0, offset + 1, offset + 2, offset + 3, offset + 4, offset + 5 );

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, recipient.vertices);
}
```

However when I draw it, it looks disjointed like this:

[image]

I was wondering how to fix that issue and how to make a generalized function that could take an arbitrary amount of rows / columns and compute the necessary vertices to generate an MxN grid.

I was looking at [this site](http://www.corehtml5.com/trianglestripfundamentals.php) specifically but I can't figure out where the trianglestrip variable comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was asked just a few days ago. Here's one answer

[Generate grid mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408593/generate-grid-mesh/35411856#35411856)

In your particular case though a 1 unit rectangle has these points

```
0,0      1,0
 +--------+
 |        |
 |        |
 |        |
 |        |
 +--------+
0,1      1,1
```

So your vertices should be

```
recipient.vertices.push( 
  vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,1,0), vec3(0,1,0), 
  vec3(1,0,0), vec3(1,1,0), vec3(0,0,0) );
```

There's no `2`s

Of course there are many other combinations and orders of those 4 points that will make a rectangle.

I usually choose this order

```
0         1 4 
 +--------+
 |        |
 |        |
 |        |
 |        |
 +--------+
2 3       5
```

I don't think there is any particular reason for one order or another except to deal with [culling](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) (search for *culling* on that page)

In your particular case though you're also using `TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Let me first say AFAIK *no professional game developers use `TRIANGLE_STRIP`. They all use plain `TRIANGLES`. It just makes everything easier so you might want to switch to `TRIANGLES`. For a strip through you only need 4 points

```
recipient.vertices.push( 
  vec3(0,0,0), vec3(0,1,0), vec3(0,1,0), vec3(1,1,0)); 
recipient.indices.push( 
  offset + 0, offset + 1, offset + 2, offset + 3);
```

Just in case it's not clear. Given 6 points `TRIANGLES` will draw 2 triangles consisting of

```
triangle 0 = points 0,1,2 
triangle 1 = points 3,4,5
```

whereas `TRIANGLE_STRIP` will draw 4 triangles consisting of

```
triangle 0 = points 0,1,2 
triangle 1 = points 1,2,3 
triangle 2 = points 2,3,4 
triangle 3 = points 3,4,5
```

Also, It's not at all clear what your code is doing. Maybe `recipeient.xxx.push` is doing some really inefficient magic but there's no indication the vertices you're creating are actually being used by WebGL when you call `gl.drawArrays`. Normally there would need to be some calls to `gl.bufferData` or `gl.bufferSubData` to give the data to WebGL. Also you're recreating indices but `gl.drawArrays` does not use indices.

Comment: Thank you, I have a quad now and I'm using TRIANGLE instead of TRIANGLE_STRIP. I was looking at your code for the grid mesh and I was wondering if the position array you made would be the vertex coordinates I need to make the mesh?

Comment: Yes, the position array from the grid mesh example would be the vertex coorinates. You probably want to multiply them by the width and height you want the mesh to be. The code generates a unit mesh (a mesh that is 1 unit width and 1 unit tall).

Comment: Thank you, so using your code I have something like this:

... 
recipient.vertices.push( vec3(u, v, 1))
recipient.normals.push( vec3(0, 0, 1))
...
recipient.indices.push(rowOffset0, rowOffset0 + 1, rowOffset1);
recipient.indices.push(rowOffset1, rowOffset0 + 1, rowOffset1 + 1);

So basically instead of pushing to the positions array and the indices array, I push to my recipients and then draw. Is that the correct way to do this? Right now in my browser, it's just rendering a line and not a plane for me.

Comment: That looks correct. you might want to try `recipient.vertices.push( vec3(u * 5, v * 5, 1))` or some other width or height. If you can't figure out the issue post your working code in a new question

Comment: So I tried that and it still renders as a line. I've asked a separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532178/making-a-mesh-plane-in-webgl-with-triangles